# Serialize java class with custom object attributes

Tags: java, mysql, serialization, ebean

I would like to serialize a Java class on my MySQL database using Ebean ORM.

My class definition is similar to the following:

```
public class Test implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @Lob
    private MyClass1 obj1;
    @Lob
    private MyClass2 obj2;
    ...
    ...
    //getters and setters
}
```

where my classes MyClass1 and MyClass2 are basically wrappers for a

```
float[]
```

and an

```
Hashmap<String, Float>
```

and both implement Serializable interface.

I don't want to have to create a class with:

```
@Lob
byte[] obj1bytes;
@Transient
MyClass1 obj1Obj;
@Lob
byte[] obj2bytes;
@Transient
MyClass2 obj2Obj;
//getters and setters
```

What I would like to obtain is serialize and deserialize this class automatically WITHOUT having to use byte[] arrays to hold obj1 and obj2 in my Test class to a MySQL table in two LongBlob fields using

```
Ebean.save(testClassInstance);
Ebean.find(Test.class, ID);
```

EDIT1: MyClass1 is defined as following:

```
public class MyClass1 implements Interface1 {
    private float[] vector;
    public MyClass1 () {
    }
    public MyClass1 (float[] vector) {
        this.vector = vector;
    }
    public float[] getVector() {
        return vector;
    }
    public void setVector(float[] vector) {
       this.vector = vector;
    }
    @Override
    public byte[] serialize() throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
        out.writeObject(object);
        out.close();            
        return byteOut.toByteArray();
    }
    @Override
    public void deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream byteInt = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream out = new ObjectInputStream(byteInt);
        vector = (float[])out.readObject();
    }
    @Override
    public float cossim(MyClass1 v) throws Exception {
        method logic
    }
    @Override
    public MyClass1 add(MyClass1 v) throws Exception {
        method logic
   }
}
```

MyClass2 is defined as MyClass1, only that instead of float[] vector I have a HashMap < String, Float > (). The only differences worth noting are serialize() and deserialize():

```
@Override
public byte[] serialize() throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outStream);
    out.writeInt(map.size());
    Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        out.writeUTF(key);
        out.writeFloat(map.get(key));
    }
    return outStream.toByteArray();
}

@Override
public void deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    try {
      ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inStream);
      this.map = new HashMap<>();
      int n = in.readInt();
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        map.put(in.readUTF(), in.readFloat());
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not necessary to wrap `float[]` and `HashMap<String,float>` as they themselves are serializable.

Another thing is that if `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` are serializable than you can use `@Lob`. According to [**this wikibook**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes),

> By default in JPA any Serializable attribute that is not a
>   relationship or a basic type (String, Number, temporal, primitive),
>   will be serialized to a BLOB field.

In that wikibook, there is also an example using `@Lob` for the class `Image`.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    ...
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Lob
    private Image picture;
    ...
}
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I already read that wikiboook and did exactly the same: I annotated my MyClass1 and MyClass2 objects with @Lob, but when I execute Ebean.save(testInstance) every field gets saved in the db except those two. I need to wrap those float[] and HashMap<String, float> because they need some specific operations done on them that require the creation of two classes.

Comment: @Andrea Can you post your MyClass1 and MyClass2?

Comment: I modified my question to include MyClass1 and MyClass2 definitions (most of them actually)

Answer (score 0):

I did some coding after your reply.

Condition: The fields of ClassB should be serializable and the fields of fields should be serializable and ....

ClassB:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClassB implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String b;

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

ClassA:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

@Entity
public class ClassA implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    String a;
    @Lob
    ClassB b;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public ClassB getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(ClassB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

Here, ClassA contains ClassB object. You can add any logic in ClassB and it works. I have small problem with your overriding of serialize and deserialize. I think you do not need to do that. It will be done by default as it is serialized. And at last, these codes do work as I have tried it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried your exact code and it does not work. Can you please share your ebean.properties? Ebean does not create LOB columns in my MySQL database. Have you run your sample code? Which components did you use? Which version of Ebean library did you use?

Comment: No errors at all, Ebean completely ignores all my Lob that are not byte[].

Comment: Actually I am using Hibernate.

Comment: I thought I clearly stated I'm working with Ebean, not Hibernate... You could at least tell me you were working with Hibernate, so I would have not spent time trying to figure out why I couldn't get it working but you were...

Comment: I just watched ORM and next thing is at that time I did not know about Ebean. Sorry for that.